# Prove that the rank of a matrix is the number of non-zero rows of its row-reduced form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

As a reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080554/how-to-calculate-matrix-rank) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551819/regarding-ranks-of-row-echelon-form-matrices) and similarly many sources, it has been sait that the rank of a matrix, say $A$, is the number of non-zero rows of the row-reduced form of $A$.

However,  **why is this the case ? How can we prove it ?**

I mean in the second question that I have linked, the answerer says the non-zero row form a basis etc. which I think does not connect to the rank of matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you agree that row operations don't affect the rank of the matrix, then this follows from one of the definitions of the rank of a matrix, which is the dimension of the row space of the matrix.

The rows of that matrix span a vector space, and the dimension of that vector space is equal to the number of non-zero vectors that span it.

The dimensionality is clearly not greater than the number of rows. But its also not less: there are no redundant vectors, because every row contains an entry where it is the only non-zero element in its column, so it is impossible to build that row from a linear combination of the other rows.

Comment: Intuitively, I can see that the row operations should not affect the rank of a matrix, but mathematically I can not prove it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140853/why-is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-invariant-under-row-operations